# Bind Input Values in Modal with Angular not working with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

We are trying to build a Profile page with an option to open a Modal window to edit the same user information.  We are using **Angular 4 / TypeScript / Firebase / AngularFire2**.  We are seeing the user's profile data on the main screen but it is not showing up as the "value" for the input fields when the Modal window is launched (see picture).

The displayed values (blacked out) show up but not the same data when trying to edit.

[image]

**Firebase Node Content Example (Node: /users)**
Note: This was copied from the Internet browser to get a copy of the structure of a record for the /users node.

```
kGAMmM5PYvMemxYrXcjaH3gOOYB4
 address: "1234 Fake Street"
 businessLinkCode: ""
 city: "Faketown"
 email: "john@smith.com"
 modifiedDate: "2017-07-25"
 modifiedTime: "1:20:33 pm"
 name: "John Smith"
 phone: "1234567890"
 photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tow..."
 position: "Assistant"
 state_: "North Fake State"
 zipCode: "12345"
```

**Component TS (abbreviated):**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageTitleService } from '../../core/page-title/page-title.service';
import {fadeInAnimation} from '../../core/route-animation/route.animation';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
...
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
...
constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private userService: UserService,
    private pageTitleService: PageTitleService,
    private modalService: NgbModal
) {
    this.users = db.list('/users');
}
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.pageTitleService.setTitle('User Profile');
    this.authService.user$.subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = this.userService.getUser(user.uid)

    });
}
...
// MODAL
open(content) {
    this.authService.user$.subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = this.userService.getUser(user.uid)
    });
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
    this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start">
<div fxFlex.gt-md="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex="100">
    <div class="user-content">
        <md-card id="profile">
            <div fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start" class="user-profile">
                <div class="user-contact-info">
                    <button style="background-color: #004380; color: white; height: 45px; width: 45px; min-width: 0; padding: 1.5%; border-radius: 50%;" (click)="open(editProfilePicture)" md-raised-button class="mrgn-b-md"><md-icon>image</md-icon></button>
                    <div class="perfect-circle" style="height: 240px; width: 240px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0%;">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" [src]="(user | async)?.profile_imageUrl" alt="{{ (user | async)?.name }}" title="{{ (user | async)?.name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-list">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center">{{ (user | async)?.name }}</h2>
                        <p style="font-weight: light; font-size: medium; text-align: center"> {{ (user | async)?.position }}</p>
                        <button style="background-color: #004380; color: white; margin-bottom: 10%;" (click)="open(editProfile)" md-raised-button class="mrgn-b-md">EDIT PROFILE</button>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope mat-text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>E-mail:</strong><a href="mailto:{{ (user | async)?.email }}"> {{ (user | async)?.email }}</a></p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-phone mat-text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>Phone:</strong><a href="tel:{{ (user | async)?.phone }}"> {{ (user | async)?.phone }}</a></p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker mat-text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong> Address:</strong><span> {{ (user | async)?.address }}</span></p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa fa-map mat-text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>City:</strong><span> {{ (user | async)?.city }}</span></p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa fa-globe mat-text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong>State:</strong><span> {{ (user | async)?.state_ }}</span></p> 
                    </div>
                </div>


                <ng-template #editProfile let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">   
                        <div>
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Profile</h4>
                                    <button style="background-color: transparent; border: none; cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                                        <i style="font-size: large; color: gray" class="fa fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(editUser)" class="form">
                                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                                    <input mdInput placeholder="First and Last Name" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.name" [formControl]="nameFormControl">
                                </md-input-container>
                                <div class="flex-layout">
                                    <md-input-container class="half-width">
                                        <input mdInput placeholder="Position/Title" type="text" name="position" [(ngModel)]="editUser.position" [formControl]="positionFormControl">
                                    </md-input-container>
                                    <md-input-container class="half-width">
                                        <span mdPrefix>+1 &nbsp;</span>
                                        <input mdInput placeholder="Phone" #phone maxlength="10" type="tel" name="phone" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.phone" [formControl]="phoneFormControl">
                                        <md-hint align="end">{{phone.value.length}} / 10</md-hint> 
                                    </md-input-container>
                                </div>
                                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                                    <input mdInput placeholder="Address"  type="text" name="address" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.address" [formControl]="addressFormControl">
                                </md-input-container>
                                <div class="flex-layout">
                                    <md-input-container class="third-width">
                                        <input mdInput placeholder="City"  type="text" name="city" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.city" [formControl]="cityFormControl">
                                    </md-input-container>
                                    <md-input-container class="third-width">
                                        <input mdInput placeholder="State"  type="text" name="state" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.state_" [formControl]="state_FormControl">
                                    </md-input-container>
                                    <md-input-container class="third-width">
                                        <input mdInput placeholder="Zipcode"  #zipcode maxlength="5" name="zipCode" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.zipCode" [formControl]="zipCodeFormControl">
                                        <md-hint align="end">{{zipcode.value.length}} / 5</md-hint>
                                    </md-input-container>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <button style="background-color: #004380; color: white;" md-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="submit(user) + c('Close click')" class="mrgn-b-md">SAVE ACCOUNT</button>
                                <button style="background-color: gray; color: white;" md-raised-button type="button" class="mrgn-b-md" (click)="c('Close click')">CANCEL</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </ng-template> 

                <ng-template #editProfilePicture let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">   
                        <div>
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Profile Picture</h4>
                                    <button style="background-color: transparent; border: none; cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                                        <i style="font-size: large; color: gray" class="fa fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                                <img class="img-responsive" [src]="(user | async)?.profile_imageUrl" alt="{{ (user | async)?.name }}" title="{{ (user | async)?.name }}">
                            <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(user)" class="form">
                                <br>
                                <input type="file" name="image" class="inputfile form-control" required value="upload" (change)="filebuttoni($event)"/>
                                <br>
                                <button style="background-color: #004380; color: white;" md-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="submit(user) + c('Close click')" class="mrgn-b-md">SAVE IMAGE</button>
                                <button style="background-color: gray; color: white;" md-raised-button type="button" class="mrgn-b-md" (click)="c('Close click')">CANCEL</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </ng-template> 

            </div>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is in the content?

Comment: I updated the question with an example record from our /users node in Firebase to try to help. Thanks!

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the way that the ngModel was being applied to the input elements.  At this time, I'm not deep enough into Angular to explain why, but it does work and allows me to move forward.

**Code that was not working:**

```
<input mdInput placeholder="First and Last Name" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="editUser.name" [formControl]="nameFormControl">
```

**Code that does work:**

```
<input mdInput placeholder="First and Last Name" type="text" name="name" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.name" [formControl]="nameFormControl">
```

As you can see the [(ngModel)] got switched to [ngModel] and I reworked the databinding property to "(editUser | async)?.name" which puts it in line with how the displaying of the same field goes when used just for display.

**Form Code Replacement:**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateUser(editUser)" class="form">
    <md-input-container class="full-width">
        <input mdInput placeholder="First and Last Name" type="text" name="name" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.name" [formControl]="nameFormControl">
    </md-input-container>
    <div class="flex-layout">
        <md-input-container class="half-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Position/Title" type="text" name="position" [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.position" [formControl]="positionFormControl">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="half-width">
            <span mdPrefix>+1 &nbsp;</span>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Phone" #phone maxlength="15" type="tel" name="phone" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.phone" [formControl]="phoneFormControl">
            <md-hint align="end">{{phone.value.length}} / 15</md-hint> 
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <md-input-container class="full-width">
        <input mdInput placeholder="Address"  type="text" name="address" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.address" [formControl]="addressFormControl">
    </md-input-container>
    <div class="flex-layout">
        <md-input-container class="third-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="City"  type="text" name="city" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.city" [formControl]="cityFormControl">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="third-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="State"  type="text" name="state" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.state_" [formControl]="state_FormControl">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="third-width">
            <input mdInput placeholder="Zipcode"  #zipcode maxlength="5" name="zipCode" required [ngModel]="(editUser | async)?.zipCode" [formControl]="zipCodeFormControl">
            <md-hint align="end">{{zipcode.value.length}} / 5</md-hint>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button style="background-color: #004380; color: white;" md-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="mrgn-b-md">SAVE ACCOUNT</button>
    <button style="background-color: gray; color: white;" md-raised-button type="button" class="mrgn-b-md" (click)="c('Close click')">CANCEL</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think that the most important thing you did was to add a "name" property. I think that for the double binding to work, the input components must have a "name"